# Can we delete saved password programatically from firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I want to delete saved Username/Password for a domain from the firefox. So is there anyway we can do it using JavaScript or ColdFusion.

Comment: What version of Firefox? `autocomplete="off"` is an HTML5 attribute.

Comment: Not with Coldfusion, as CF is server-side

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I think this is not possible, because that would be a security risk You could try turning it off to prevent saving further passwords. Another option is to rename the form fields or invalidating the passwords.

Comment: Actually in my current Login Page  contains two fields (Username/Password) . Now I designed another Login Page with same fields putting Autocomplete=OFF in the form tag for security reasons.But the saved Username and Password in the browser are still coming in text field auto-complete panel.So is there anyway to prevent this.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy - just to clarify. You said _putting Autocomplete=OFF in the form tag_. Try putting `autocomplete="off"` in the `<input>` tags and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

[Autocomplete="off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature) goes back to the days of MSIE5. It's an attribute of the FORM tag, not the INPUT tag.

Are the ID and Password pre-populated when you come back to the form? If so, then it may be the browser's built-in "Save this password" feature for forms. The `autocomplete` attribute should disable the "show previous data" functionality.

Comment: How can I disable the show previous data functionality using auto complete?

Comment: The "autocomplete" attribute should take care of that. My company uses it and we don't get any previously entered data in those fields.