# Remove saved Usernames and passwords of browser from web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, browser, passwords

In my web application I want to remove the username,password which are automatically stored by browser on click of remember me.

I know this is browser property but is there anyway to remove this on loading of my website and clearing all saved username,password of my website..

Thanks & Regards...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we delete saved password programatically from firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746679/can-we-delete-saved-password-programatically-from-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenUsername" name="username"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenPassword" name="password"/>

<form id="theForm" action="/your/login" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>      
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  $("#theForm").submit(function() {
     $("#hiddenUsername").val($("#username").val());
     $("#hiddenPassword").val($("#password").val());
  });      
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/8nGTr/170/), Will work as you want(Note: just to check how it's working with hiddenfields)

Answer (score 3):

Best way I've found of doing it thusfar, is faking the browser into thinking there are multiple username/password fields on the form. The browser's save username/password generally look for the first password field and the field previous to it for the username, so I have added new fields to the page in a hidden div, outside of my form to resolve the problem

```
<div style="display:none;">
   <input type="text" id="fake_username"/>
   <input type="password" id="fake_password"/>
</div>
<form action="..." method="POST">
   <input type="text" id="username"/>
   <input type="password" id="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I also generally add the `autocomplete="off"` to my form and input elements, either directly or via a jquery script (below) on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off") });
```

Comment: might be this is working in C#,but I am working on C# MVC and it dosen't works as browser plays on name...thanks for your time....

Comment: my example has nothing to do with C#, it's purely html. I have used this method in many mvc applications that have been used in enterprise level websites where saving of passwords is highly discouraged. I will search for the source of how most browsers search for password fields for saving

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible to remove saved passwords but you can prevent saving by

```
<form id="login" action="loginURL" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: autocomplete will not help in saving passwords on clicked by user... "save password" of browser.....thanks for this...

Comment: but user didn't get previous usernames

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers implement integrated password management: when the user enters a username and password for a site, the browser offers to remember it for the user. When the user visits the site again, the browser autofills the login fields with the stored values.

Additionally, the browser enables the user to choose a master password that the browser will use to encrypt stored login details.

Even without a master password, in-browser password management is generally seen as a net gain for security. Since users do not have to remember passwords that the browser stores for them, they are able to choose stronger passwords than they would otherwise.

For this reason, many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields:

If a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11).

If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.